# Discord.js: How to automatically get the channel id where the command is triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I basically want to get the channel id of the channel where the message was sent.

I could get it manually, but it would be nicer to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `let channelID = message.channel.id` in the message event.

From documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel

Comment: huh, quite simple. I thought it would be more complicated.

Comment: Weird. The `discord.com/developers/` docs say `message.channel_id` (as opposed to `message.channel.id`). If you can get arbitrary properties of the channel as well, that's good news.

Comment: @Cat you need to look at discord.js documentation not the discord developers one, it is much different

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Discord docs, it looks like if you have an object representing a [message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object) (and that object is assigned to a variable called `myMessage`), you can **get the channel id** with

```
let myChannelid = myMessage.channel_id; // <== THE CHANNEL ID
```

If you want to request the channel itself, you can **make a string representing a URL** like:

```
let myUrl = "https://discord.com/api/channels/" + myChannelid;
```

Then if you **send an [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request** to that URL, the response you get back should include an object representing the [channel](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel).
NOTE: If you don't already know (and assuming the response Discord provides is actually a JSON string), you'd convert it to a JavaScript object (one of whose properties will be your `channel` object) like: `let imAnObject = JSON.parse(myResponse);` ... and the easiest to see what's inside the response might be to just use `console.log(imAnObject);`

Comment: This is already handled by discord.js so the process is much simpler with it. What you have done instead is like doing it from scratch.